# Can't specify the exact range in Excel vba macro

Tags: excel, vba

Today is my first day fighting the VBA macros in Excel. All I want to do is to specify a column, get the distinct values from it and copy them in another column, found on a different sheet. I was reading a lot and this is what I came up with :

```
Sub TestS()
    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = Worksheets(3).Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
    Worksheets(3).Range(Cells(3, 1), Cells(lastRow, 1)).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=Worksheets(2).Range("A3"), Unique:=True
End Sub
```

lastRow currently points to the correct position, but I get the error :

> Run-time error 1004 The extract range has a missing or invalid field name.

Obviously there is something wrong with the syntax but I tried many different ways and none of them is working.

Comment: worked ok for me - what exactly is the error?

Comment: `Run-time error 1004 The extract range has a missing or invalid field name.`

Comment: Btw does `CopyToRange:=Worksheets(2).Range("A3")` means that it will start from A3 and it will copy all the unique elements, the program has found in the specified column?

Comment: No - it means it will copy the unique items in sheet 3 column A to `A3` in sheet2

Comment: In that case how can I specify to copy them in Column A in sheet2 starting from A3, so that the first element is in A3, the second in A4 and so on?

Comment: Sorry, thats what I meant. It will copy them to sheet 2 starting in A3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just qualify **Cells():**

```
Sub TestS()
    Dim lastRow As Long
    With Worksheets(3)
        lastRow = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(lastRow, 1)).AdvancedFilter _
            Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
            CopyToRange:=Worksheets(2).Range("A3"), Unique:=True
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Be sure we are referencing the proper **Worksheet**

Comment: yes while debugging I can see the value of the columns and it is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Tasks like these I suggest using simple SQL queries. This way you establish a connection to the source worksheet that can be refreshed at any time (like a PivotTable) and the code is more simple and flexible. The query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM [Sheet1$]
```

How to use SQL in Excel? Look for "Microsoft Query" in the "Data" ribbon, section External data. Or simply download my Add-In for Excel here: http://blog.tkacprow.pl/?page_id=130

Comment: I am exporting the data from a DB so I could have done all the manipulations there, but I want to learn how to write macros in vba.